# Symfony2: Bundle Configuration not available in container

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, configuration, bundle

I set up a bundle which defines some options via Configuration.php and the config three builder, which resides inside the bundle.

I want to put the configuration into the /root/app/config/config.yml file, but have the configuration be available inside the bundle via

```
$config = $container->getParameter('namespace');
```

So far, I can see the configuration being available via

```
bin/console debug:config namespace
```

but if I get the configuration inside the bundle code via

```
$config = $container->getParameter('namespace');
```

an exception gets thrown: "The parameter "namespace" must be defined" which it is, but the exception tells me otherwise.

My current Configuration.php:

```
class NamespaceExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood configuration and parameters. If you want access your configuration via parameters, you should set a parameter based on your configuration:

```
$container->setParameter('namespace', $config['namespace']);
```